# 'cannot convert from...' error during callback assignations (migrated code from C)

Tags: c, callback, c++-cli

I'm migrating some lines coded on C to C++/CLI (UI Windows Form based on .NET). One of my problems comes when I try to do this kind of assignation:

```
myCallbacks.cbf_data_write = this->dataWriteFunc;
```

In this case, dataWriteFunc is defined as:

```
PNIO_IOXS dataWriteFunc(PNIO_UINT32, PNIO_DEV_ADDR *, PNIO_UINT32, PNIO_UINT8 *, PNIO_IOXS);
```

And myCallbacks is declared as

```
PNIOD_CBF_FUNCTIONS myCallbacks;
```

with

```
typedef struct {
    PNIO_UINT32                      size;                      /* size of struct = sizeof(PNIO_CBF_FUNCTIONS) */
    PNIO_CBF_DATA_WRITE              cbf_data_write;            /* mandatory */
    PNIO_CBF_DATA_READ               cbf_data_read;             /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_ASYNC_REC_READ         cbf_async_rec_read;        /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_ASYNC_REC_WRITE        cbf_async_rec_write;       /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_SYNC_ALARM_DONE        cbf_sync_alarm_done;       /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_ASYNC_CONNECT_IND      cbf_async_connect_ind;     /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_ASYNC_OWNERSHIP_IND    cbf_async_ownership_ind;   /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_ASYNC_INDATA_IND       cbf_async_indata_ind;      /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_SYNC_DISCONNECT_IND    cbf_sync_disconnect_ind;   /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_SYNC_DATA_STATUS_IND   cbf_sync_data_status_ind;  /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_ASYNC_PRM_END_IND      cbf_async_prm_end_ind;     /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_SYNC_STOPPED           cbf_sync_device_stopped;   /* mandatory */
    PNIOD_CBF_ASYNC_IRT_INIT_INPUTS  cbf_async_irt_init_inputs; /* mandatory for IRT top */
    PNIOD_CBF_SYNC_CP_STOP_REQ       cbf_sync_cp_stop_req;      /* optional */
    PNIOD_CBF_SYNC_START_LED_FLASH   cbf_sync_start_led_flash;  /* optional */
    PNIOD_CBF_SYNC_STOP_LED_FLASH    cbf_sync_stop_led_flash;   /* optional */
    PNIOD_CBF_RESERVED
} ATTR_PACKED PNIOD_CBF_FUNCTIONS;
```

Also:

```
typedef PNIO_IOXS    (*PNIO_CBF_DATA_WRITE) /* write data to IO stack (local ==> remote) */
       (PNIO_UINT32          DevHndl,       /* Handle for Multidevice */
        PNIO_DEV_ADDR      * pAddr,         /* geographical address */
        PNIO_UINT32          BufLen,        /* length of the submodule input data */
        PNIO_UINT8         * pBuffer,       /* Ptr to data buffer to write to */
        PNIO_IOXS            Iocs);         /* remote (io controller) consumer status */
```

So, what exactly I'm doing wrong? VS2012 gives me next error:

```
Error   4   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'PNIO_IOXS (__thiscall CP1626::* )(PNIO_UINT32,PNIO_DEV_ADDR *,PNIO_UINT32,PNIO_UINT8 *,PNIO_IOXS)' to 'PNIO_CBF_DATA_WRITE' c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\ui_cp1626\ui_cp1626\Profinet_IDevice.h    513 1   UI_CP1626
```

What's the correct form to associate callbacks in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert thiscall function (non-static class member function) to ordinary function. The problem is non-static class members take extra implicit argument, the pointer to class object aka `this`, so dataWriteFunc's implicit signature is:

```
PNIO_IOXS dataWriteFunc(CP1626 *this, PNIO_UINT32, PNIO_DEV_ADDR *,
                        PNIO_UINT32, PNIO_UINT8 *, PNIO_IOXS);
```

, note the 1st argument, it's implicit presence is what gives function "__thiscall" attribute. If you declare this function as

```
static PNIO_IOXS dataWriteFunc(PNIO_UINT32, PNIO_DEV_ADDR *,
                               PNIO_UINT32, PNIO_UINT8 *, PNIO_IOXS);
```

then the error will go away. Note that inside static methods `this` is not available.